# One page menu active state as same as hover

Tags: css, wordpress

I have a one page site with custom (simple) `ul` menu,

The menu items are image based like 5 `li`, each 50px by 50px with different background image for each `li` item, when you hover over them, background image changes.

like;

```
li#home {
    background: url(imagea.jpg);
}

li#home:hover {
    background: url(imagehover.jpg);
}
```

It works fine but the problem is that it's one page site and I want that when I'm over a specific section, that sections' menu should have its menu to be same as it's on hover, sorta like active image.

Comment: Explore javascript solutions, since you'll need to trigger an event to apply the change and CSS won't know when that event (i.e: section comes into view and is there for active) is triggered.

Comment: You should to this in Javascript, not in CSS.

Answer (score 2):

Use JavaScript to add ,`.active` class to the element, and modify your css rules like this.

```
li#home {
    background: url(imagea.jpg);
}

li#home:hover, li#home.active{
    background: url(imagehover.jpg);
}
```

jQuery code:

```
$("element").on('click', function (){
    $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

---

### Edit: A jQuery demo

HTML

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li class="menuItem">One</li>
    <li class="menuItem">Two</li>
    <li class="menuItem">Three</li>
    <li class="menuItem">Four</li>
</ul>
```

JavaScript

```
$('li.menuItem').click(function(){
    $('li.menuItem').removeClass('active')
    .filter(this).addClass('active');
})
```

CSS

```
li{
    color:blue;
    cursor:pointer;
}
li.active{
    color:red;
}
```

I made [a Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nipunasudha/xc9kk2qt/), take a look.

Comment: Thanks, that seems logical. I'm not very experienced in Jquery. Active class will be added to ul?

Comment: No active class should be added to each element when you click on it. And it should be removed from the element when the section is not active. If you are inexperienced with jQuery, I will update the answer to be more detailed. Is it fine?

Comment: Yes please. Thanks

Comment: @IrfanSaleem I added a simple example and a fiddle.